# MS-Access DISTINCTROW dosen't work anymore if linked tables a stored on SQL2008-Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access

I have a query in MS-Access like this:

```
select DISTINCTROW companies.* from companies, contacts, companies left join contacts on contacts.com_uid = companies.com_uid (This is the ms-access form of a standard "left-join")
```

[Companies] and [contacts] are linked views on a sql-server 2008, ODBC driver is "SQL server native client 10.0". Both views looks like "select * from [companies] where deleted = 0" and "select * from [contacts] where delete = 0"

The result is wrong since companies are show as many contacts there are.

If the Views are stored on a SQL2000 and linked with the ODBC-driver "SQL Server" everything is fine: All the companies are shown exactly once.

Are there any solutions to get the result with DISTINCTROW again?

Comment: Sorry, i added some facts to the question and be aware that ms-access uses annother syntax for such standard left-joins.

Comment: It is very difficult to get the question on the real point, please have a look at my comments to David-W-Fentons answer, thanks.

Comment: Why did you flag your own question as *not a real question*?

Comment: @Gumbo: As you can see, this thread turned into a discussion about the possibilities over different syntax of 'left join'. As a result it is not possible to point out the real question. So i decided to discard this question and i started new questions - hopefully better formulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's stop talking about the syntax of a left-join in ms-access. Fact is that if the linked tables are views on sql-server 2000:

```
create view [companies] as
select * from [TabCompanies] where deleted  = 0
```

and

```
create view [contacts] as
select * from [TabContcts] where deleted = 0
```

These views are ODBC-linked-tables in a ms-access 2003/2007 mdb. 
The questions shows up in ms-access on a query like

```
select distinctrow [companies].* from [companies] left join [contacts] on [companies].com_uid = contacts.com_uid] where [contacts].[function] like 'C*'
```

(lets forget that alternative syntax and look on the result assuming that the left join works without an error or syntaxerror)

This DISTINCTROW is a ms-access feature and not know in sql-server and for my point of view the result is the same like DISTINCT but works also even if there are columns with datatype of images par example.

All together we expect by now the same like Catcall in his answer said "select * from companies" BUT IT IS NOT, why?

This is only an excerpt of the whole query and may be makes no sense for production but it shows the changed behaviour wehn sql2008 is connected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised it executes that query at all. You're specifying the table "contacts" twice.

Your LEFT JOIN should return every row from "companies". Since you're not retrieving any columns from contacts, I'm pretty sure your query is equivalent to

```
SELECT * 
FROM companies
```

as long as "companies" means what it does in ordinary language.

If that turns out not to be the case, you can hand the burden off to SQL Server either by creating a view in SQL Server, or by creating a [passthrough query](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/303968) in Access. A passthrough query will have to be written in your server's dialect of SQL (SQL Server 2008 dialect of SQL).

---

Your revision, reproduced below, does nothing to change my earlier comments.

```
select DISTINCTROW companies.* 
from companies, contacts, companies 
left join contacts on contacts.com_uid = companies.com_uid 
(This is the ms-access form of a standard "left-join")
```

That's *not* Access's form of a left join. Access won't allow this:

```
from companies, contacts, companies 
left join contacts
```

because you're now specifying *both* tables twice.

Based on your edit, I'd say the query you're trying to write is still equivalent to

```
SELECT * 
FROM companies
```

What do you get if you run *that*?

Comment: Yes i know the passthrough queries b ut thats not the problem here - SQL2000 as backend works fine sql2008 not.

Comment: Then the query is wronger. Now you're specifying both tables twice. And that's not remotely close to Access's standard way of doing a left join. If you're really using Access, it should give you "Synatax error in JOIN operation".

Comment: Believe me this syntax works fine, it is ms-access and this way there is no need for () even there are more tables involved.
This is not the question! It works fine since years with linked tables on sql2000 but now with linked tables on a sql2008 there is no syntax error but a wrong result: why? What does sql2008 other than sql2000?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of DISTINCTROW is to make editable the two sides of an N:1 join. With a Cartesian product (`from companies, contacts, companies`), the result cannot be editable, so DISTINCTROW has no advantage over DISTINCT.

Secondly, no matter what you say, it is not possible to have the same table twice in a FROM clause without an alias. The SQL you've posted could not have worked in any version of Access.

The only way I can possible imagine there's any sense in what you've posted is if you've omitted a WHERE clause.

EDIT BASED ON COMMENTS:

This should work:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT companies.*
  FROM companies INNER JOIN contacts ON companies.com_uid = contacts.com_uid
  WHERE contacts.function LIKE "C*"
```

First off, I'd assume a normal N:1 relationship between contacdts and companies (i.e., many contact records are linked to any single company record), so with both tables in the FROM clause, you do need a DISTINCT to return a single row for each company.

Secondly, if you place criteria on the table on the many side of the JOIN, there's no reason to attempt to use a LEFT JOIN, as it won't change the records returned (use a LEFT JOIN when you want to return records regardless of whether or not there are records in the table on the many side of the JOIN). So, an INNER JOIN is going to do the job for you, and be more efficient (outer JOINs are just slower, even with criteria).

Comment: Ok, sorry i am confused. Lets narrow down this sql-syntax:

Comment: Ok, sorry i am confused. Lets narrow down this sql-syntax: You omitted something essential: "(from companies, contacts, companies left join contacts on ...)" as i see the second companies is NOT a further table but rather part of the LEFT JOIN.
I know that this doesn't work on SQL-Server or as passthrough statemenet in Access, but as native ms-access code it works fine since  ms-access97 until ms-acces2010 (as mdb not as accdb!).

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: You are right, the sense of this lies in the where-clause and this goes like that for example "where contact.function like 'C*'" to get all companies with contacts with function like CEO, CIO, CFO, COO ... BUT i only want one company if there are more than one c-function-contact in a particular company therefore the DISTINCTROW.

Comment: The JOIN syntax is still not right. It would be `FROM companies LEFT JOIN contacts ON...` -- it does NOT repeat a table already in the FROM clause. You have both tables twice, once in the JOIN, and once each listed in the FROM. This is just not correct, and throws an error when attempted within Access.

Comment: If the WHERE clause does not refine the relationship between the two tables, it is of no relevance here. That is, if you're not using implicit JOINs it really doesn't matter to your question.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton: Thanks a lot for your patience. You are right, i can't explain my problem.